# Invalid operands comparing a struct to null

Tags: c

I'm trying to debug the following error I have in my code:

```
#define MAX_PATTERNS 10

typedef struct _kv {
    char* key;
    char* val;
} KV;

void compile(char* pattern)
{
    
    KV patterns[MAX_PATTERNS] = {NULL,};

    for (int idx=0; idx < MAX_PATTERNS; idx++) {
        KV item = patterns[idx];
        printf("%d", item == 0);
    }

}
```

And I get the following error:

```
test.c:107:27: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('KV' (aka 'struct _kv') and 'int')
   printf("%d", item == 0);
                ~~~~ ^  ~
 error generated.
```

What am I doing wrong here? I thought that I could use a `patterns[idx] == NULL` to test when I can exit the loop (since I'm initializing the array to all zero's), but I seem to be wrong on something. Should I instead check `patterns[idx].key` to see if that's `NULL`?

I suppose one (ugly) way to check if the entire struct is zero'd is by doing:

```
printf ("Null? %s\n", 
(int) (void*) patterns[0].key + (int) (void*) patterns[0].val == 0? "true" : "false");
```

Comment: `item` is a `KV` - not a pointer to a `KV`. `item` (a struct) can't be compared directly to an int. 0. You can check if `item.key` is 0.

Comment: Structs can't be null. Only pointers can.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but the 16-byte memory address for each struct is zero'd by the initialization of the array right?

Comment: Think about it again. `item` is a struct. It has multiple fields. So which struct field do you think the `==` is comparing? In C the `==` operator cannot be use to compare compound types.

Comment: @kaylum does the 'null check' I added at the end of the question make sense? or is that just stupid.

Comment: The first comment already tells you the right way to check. `item.key == NULL`. Also, `KV item = patterns[idx];` is inefficient as it makes a copy of the entire struct. Suggest instead: `KV *item_ptr = &patterns[idx];` and then check with `item_ptr->key == NULL`. Or just `patterns[idx].key == NULL`

Comment: If NULL is a valid value for the key field, then you need to add a field like is_valid into the struct as a new member.

Comment: *"Should I instead check `patterns[idx].key` to see if that's `NULL`?"* Yes, that's exactly what you should do. And there's no need to check both `key` and `val` for NULL. If `key` is NULL, the code shouldn't look at `val`, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error message says it all... you are trying to compare a `struct _kv` and an `int`. It makes no sense to compare objects of completely different types to each other so that's illegal.

But even worse... C doesn't allow you to compare structs using `==` Not even if the structs are of the same type. Example:

```
    KV item1 = patterns[idx1];
    KV item2 = patterns[idx2];
    if (item1 == item2) puts("e");
```

will give an error like:

```
error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘KV’ {aka ‘struct _kv’} and ‘KV’ {aka ‘struct _kv’})
```

**To compare structs you need to compare the members one by one.**

You ask if it's done like:

```
(int) (void*) patterns[0].key + (int) (void*) patterns[0].val == 0
```

The answer is **NO**

Instead do

```
patterns[0].key == NULL && patterns[0].val == NULL
```

If your program compares structs several places in the code, it may be a good idea to write a dedicated compare function - like:

```
int equal_kv(const KV* a, const KV* b)
{
    return a->key == b->key && a->val == b->val;
}
```

and use it like:

```
KV item1 = patterns[idx1];
KV item2 = patterns[idx2];
if equal_kv(&item1, &item2) puts("e");
```

Answer (score -3):

In my humble point of view, I totally agree with kaylum's point. "item" 's data type is a struct and cannot be compared directly with a integer type variable or literal integer. Instead, in C++, we can use operator overloading to redefine the "==" operator for custom data types such as any custom class or struct.

Comment: Yes, we can do that in C++. However this is a C (another programming language) question, so that is inapplicable. This here is not an answer to the question being posed. It belongs in a comment at best.